# Can I use the GroupPolicy PowerShell module on non-AD standalone servers?

Tags: windows, group-policy, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to use the [GroupPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967461.aspx) PowerShell module to manipulate and read local group policy settings on a *standalone* Windows 2012R2 server.

When I try to execute the [`Get-GPOReport`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461057.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-GPOReport -All -ReportType Xml
```

I get the following error:

> Get-GPOReport : Current security context is not associated with an
>   Active Directory domain or forest.   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-GPOReport -ReportType Xml -all
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-GPOReport], ActiveDirectoryOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGpoReportCommand

I've also tried specifying my server name as well:

```
Get-GPOReport -ReportType Xml -all -server devserver01
```

But I get the same error.

I am logged in as `Administrator` on this server whilst running these commands. I also have the Group Policy Management Console installed which is a [pre-requisite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967461.aspx).

The error message:

> Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest.

Suggests I should be logged in as a Domain user, but as I mentioned this is a standalone server that is not part of an AD domain.

Is it not possible to use the GroupPolicy module cmdlets on a standalone server?

Comment: I'm confused. If there's no AD domain, then what Group Policies do you expect to interface with?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to read and change local group policy settings, i.e. settings configured via the `gpedit.msc` MMC snap-in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Group Policy` may seem synonymous with `Local Security Policy` and often in IT we talk this way.  Similar to saying Kleenex for any tissue.

Unfortunately, it's a little off.  When Microsoft refers to `Group Policy Objects` they mean just that...a *group* setting or a setting that could be applied to a group of objects.

So when Technet refers to GPOs, they mean it in the context of a domain, and not a single local security policy.

So unfortunately, **NO** you won't be able to use the GPO cmdlets on a standalone server.

Comment: So...back to `secedit` or registry hacking with procmon to see what gets changed when using `gpedit.msc` then?

Comment: Yeah `secedit` basically, and policy auditing.  You could try something like: [Netwrix Change Notifier for Active Directory](http://www.netwrix.com/top_7_freeware_tools.html) but I've never used it, so I don't even know if it'll report properly on a LSP but it says it will.

Comment: +1 Not to mention, without AD, you've no [Active Directory Web Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/04/06/active-directory-web-services-overview.aspx) for the Powershell cmdlets to talk to, so...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically true - if you're running on a WORKGROUP machine or a machine on an untrusted domain you can run the tools using the runas /netonly command to provide the credentials.

You then need to supply both the -Server and -Domain parameters
https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2023/08/activedirectory-powershell-error-get.html